# Terminal window with running command

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

Is it possible to start a new window of terminal as in Windows: `start example.bat`? It opens a new window and runs an command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command, or [`ossascript`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html).  Here are some related questions using those commands in their answers:

- [Programmatically launch Terminal.app with a specified command (and custom colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404242/programmatically-launch-terminal-app-with-a-specified-command-and-custom-colors)
- [Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window)
- [What arguments does the Mac's Terminal.app accept?](https://superuser.com/questions/579796/what-arguments-does-the-macs-terminal-app-accept)

The `open` command is more straightforward, allowing you to specify the name of a script or command to be run, as [noted in one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989446/4518274).  That describes this case (referring to [`open(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)):

```
open -a Terminal.app file
```

where *file* is the application to be opened.  You may have to give its full pathname.  The manual describes also a `--args` option which it states can be used to pass parameters to the application.