# Run a shell script in a new Terminal window from another shell script (OS X)

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, scripting

How can I make a shell script open multiple new Terminal windows that executes each their shell script? Just like asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the), but in OS X.

I've got a for-each loop which runs trough all the given arguments and should execute a script in a new Terminal window for each given argument (and pass on the argument).

This is what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in $@ do

  open -a Terminal ./somescript.sh --args $arg

done
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404242/programmatically-launch-terminal-app-with-a-specified-command-and-custom-colors

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@"; do
  osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo \"$arg\""
EOF
done
```

Then run:

```
chmod +x aboveScript
./aboveScript a b "cd ef"
```

If you like that, change the `echo` to `./somescript`.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve without osascript? I'm supposed to just use bash. I've got it working in Linux by writing `gnome-terminal -x somescript.sh $arg` and hoped to find something similar for OS X.

Comment: If you install `XQuartz` (X11 Windows for OSX) you can run `xterm -e "..."` just as on Linux.