# Execute commands in a csv file (bash / Mac)

Tags: bash, macos, csv

I have a `csv` file which includes a bunch of commands in the command line. I can just `bash` this csv file, but the commands will be executed sequentially in the same terminal. Is there a way to execute each one of these commands in a separate terminal, so that they are executed in parallel?

Example:

It's like:

```
python args1
python args2
...
python argsn
```

Comment: You can put each command in the background? There's also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404242/programmatically-launch-terminal-app-with-a-specified-command-and-custom-colors

Comment: Here is another question to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window

Comment: What exactly does your CSV file look like? In general, you should not be able to simply execute it, as the field delimiters shouldn't be considered part of the arguments.

Comment: How is that a CSV file?

Comment: Huh? Why would you have bash commands mixed in with a `csv`?

Comment: @chepner 1st row: command1 2nd row command2 and so on. There's only one cell per row.

Comment: Please show a proper example of your file else you are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Why do you want separate Terminal windows for each? Wouldn't it be better to prefix each command's output with a tag - all in one window?

Comment: @thanasissdr You just have a regular text file. It might have been exported from something (like a spreadsheet, e.g.), but that isn't really relevant.

Comment: @chepner Excuse my ignorance, but I am rather new in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do any serious software development on a Mac, I would suggest you install **homebrew** because Apple doesn't ship a package manager, but does ship ancient versions of all the tools most people use... Python, sed, PHP, Perl, awk, find, grep, make, git...

Once you have **homebrew**, I would recommend **GNU Parallel** which you can install with:

```
brew install parallel
```

Once you have **GNU Parallel**, you can run your commands in parallel with:

```
parallel --dry-run -a commands.csv
```

Or, maybe you would like the lines tagged with their names:

```
parallel --tag -a commands.csv
```

If you would like 8 to run at a time, add `-j 8`. If you want an Estimated Time of Arrival (when they should complete) add `--eta` and so on.

---

By the way, you can look for other tools, like Intel TBB, with:

```
brew search tbb
```

or pango, with:

```
brew search pango
```

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your project and remember questions, and answers, are free on StackOverflow, so come back if you get stuck.

Comment: It should show you the commands it would execute. If they look correct, you should run again but remove the `--dry-run`

Comment: The output may be buffered. Do the jobs take long?

Comment: You can try adding `--line-buffer` or `--ungroup` to get output sooner. You can also add `--job-log YourLog.txt` to get a log file.

Answer (score 2):

You basically just have a shell script already. The only difference is that instead of running it as one script, you want to run each line as a separate command. How you open a new terminal is somewhat OS-dependent, but let's assume you would just use the `xterm` command. The following will treat your script `commands.csv` (or whatever it is named) as a data file.

```
while IFS= read -r cmdline; do
    xterm -e sh -c "$cmdline" &
done < commands.csv
```

Comment: (Just noticed you tagged the question `osx`; checking how you would use the standard Terminal app instead of `xterm`.)

Comment: Yup. Depending on the line in the file, though, there are going to be some hairy quoting issues to work out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

You can run commands in the background like

```
run-command &
run-some-other-command &
etc &
```

is that something you can use?